# Web scraping, getting diffrent value from product

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning python and I am trying to build a small web scraping project. The issue I am facing is whenever I get the prices it is different from the product. I get the title, URL in correct order but price seems to be in random order. For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQER1.jpg

Code:

```
URL = 'https://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/calgary/new__used/c174l1700199a49?for-sale-by=ownr'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

price_tags = soup.find_all("div", class_="price")

prices = [
    tag.get_text(strip=True)[1:] for tag in price_tags
    if tag.get_text(strip=True).startswith('$')
]

print(prices)

# get data for title, stored in list data
data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).text, 'html.parser')
genres = [a.text.strip() for a in soup.select("div[class='title'] > a")]
data.append(genres)
print(data)

#get url for car, store it in url_storage
url_storage = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', class_="title"):
    url_storage.append(link.get('href'))
print(url_storage)
print(len(prices))
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're creating two soups. Meaning your prices come from one request but genres and urls from another one.

Also, by using `startswith("$")` you're skipping some price info e.g. swap / trade. In other words, you have to have the same number of price items as, say, title items (and urls).

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/calgary/new__used/c174l1700199a49?for-sale-by=ownr'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

prices = [tag.get_text(strip=True) for tag in (soup.select(".search-item .price"))]
titles = [a.getText(strip=True) for a in soup.select("div[class='title'] > a")]
follow_urls = [link.get("href") for link in soup.find_all("a", class_="title")]

print(len(prices))
print(len(titles))
print(len(follow_urls))
```

This outputs:

```
45
45
45
```

You can use `zip()` to get the title and price together and compare with the source HTML.